# How can use Static popover for text field?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to make a text field that use static popover for it like this :

[image]

I want it show without clicking any button and it enable when the page is loaded.

How can i make this with popover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By showing and hiding it manually using `popover.show()`.

First, you set the trigger for the popover to manual using `data-trigger='manual'`, or via javascript, then run `popover.show()` (assuming popover is your popover variable) on `$(document).ready`

HTML

```
<button id='yourPopoverButton'>Text</button>
```

Javascript

```
$('#yourPopoverButton').popover({trigger:'manual'});
$(document).ready(
    $('#yourPopoverButton').show();
)
```

Comment: i have a problem, i add a panel in my code it's gone below the menu and popover too , do you have any idea?

Comment: By `gone below`, I'm assuming that it's hidden behind the menu and popover. To adjust the order of your elements, and do things like sending the panel to the front, look into [Z-Index](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)